# Variables is not being read by ApiController in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I just started learning c#, ASP.net, and I have this issue. This is the code. I have a model in the models folder called Role.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace xrakFRS.Models {
   public class Role {
     [Key]
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public string Rolename { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
  }
```

}

This is my RolesController

```
   using xrakFRS.Data;
   using xrakFRS.Models;
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Net;
   using System.Net.Http;
   using System.Web.Http;
   using System.Web.Http.Cors;

   namespace xrakFRS.Controllers {

  [EnableCors("*", "*", "*"), RoutePrefix("api/roles")] 
  public class RolesController : ApiController{

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("getroles")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetRoles() {
        try {
            using (var context = new AppDbContext()) {
                var entries = context.Roles.ToList();
                return Ok(entries);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("postrole")]
    public IHttpActionResult PostRole([FromBody] Role role) {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);
        try {
            using (var context = new AppDbContext()) {
                context.Roles.Add(role);
                context.SaveChanges();
                return Ok("Entry was created");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
     }
```

When I try to call the api using Postman, I get this:

[image]

When I try to inspect the variables at the breakpoints, I get null values:

[image]

I get null values for "Rolename" and "Description". I am not sure why my data is not binding on the controller.

Comment: Add the `DataMemberAttribute` to your `Role` attributes or create a DTO class

Comment: try send raw json value from postman like :
{ desription: 'desc', rolename: 'name' }

Comment: i added the DataMember Attribute but it still did not work, still getting out null values.

Comment: Using **x-www-form-urlencoded** instead of form-data in Postman should work.

Comment: okay let me try this. thanks.

Comment: generally is a bad practice to use the communication with the database in the controllers .

Answer (score 0):

try sending `raw` body from Postman

```
{
  "rolename": "Admin user for the application",
  "description": "Administrator"
}
```

Comment: i even added DataMember on the role models

Answer (score 0):

go to postman body-> select raw and from dropdown menu json
then go to body and add

```
{
    "roleId":1,
    "rolename":" bla bla",
    "description" : " bla bla"
}
```

Comment: i did that it did not work, i still had the same errors

Comment: @AndeCaleb ok can you share how add the attributes in role class?

Answer (score 0):

Try using **x-www-form-urlencoded** via postman and remove [FromBody] attribute. It will automatically map varriables to the object. The code will look like:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("postrole")]
    public IHttpActionResult PostRole(Role role) {
             //Any logic here
     }
```

How the request should look like in the Postman
[Postman should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7qXf.png)